# open(HANDLE, "-|", $cmd, @args) : how to read stderr?

Tags: perl, file-io, stderr

I want to read the output of a command including the stderr into HANDLE:

```
open(HANDLE, "-|", $cmd, @args);
```

But the above command just reads the stdin?

How can I also read the stderr?

Comment: Do you want to munge STDERR and STDOUT into one file handle? In that case you'd be able to use shell redirection operators + [ShellQuote](https://metacpan.org/module/ROSCH/String-ShellQuote-1.04/ShellQuote.pm). Otherwise, you'd need something like [IPC::Run](https://metacpan.org/module/TODDR/IPC-Run-0.92/lib/IPC/Run.pm) or [IPC::Open3](https://metacpan.org/module/RJBS/perl-5.18.0/ext/IPC-Open3/lib/IPC/Open3.pm)

Comment: yes into one filehandle

Comment: @amon - that should be an answer :)

Comment: Also covered in perlfaq: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq8.html#How-can-I-capture-STDERR-from-an-external-command%3f

Comment: @DVK I am not knowledgeable enough to provide a good answer on this topic. While I can make a basic solution work, I don't consider it good enough (I'd rather use IPC::Run than open3, but can't get it to work with file handles of my choosing). May somebody who knows more about this post an answer and enlighten me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [IPC::Run](https://metacpan.org/module/TODDR/IPC-Run-0.92/lib/IPC/Run.pm) module provides a `run` function that works like a supercharged `system`. It allows us to collect the output of STDERR and STDOUT combined:

```
run [$cmd, @args], '&>', \my $output;
```

after that, the `$output` variable holds the combined output as a string.

Example:

```
use IPC::Run qw/ run /;
run ['perl', '-E say "stdout"; say STDERR "stderr"'], '&>', \my $output;
print uc $output;
```

Output:

```
STDOUT
STDERR
```

I don't know how to use a filehandle in place of the scalar reference so that the output can be read normally in a `while(<$fh>)` loop.

Comment: or `run [$cmd, @args], '>', \my $stdout, '2>', \my $stderr;`

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to look at [IPC::Open3](https://metacpan.org/module/RJBS/perl-5.18.0/ext/IPC-Open3/lib/IPC/Open3.pm) which starts a process and provide separate file handles for writing to the child, and reading the child's STDOUT and STDERR.

Answer (score -1):

I use Bash redirection as below in my perl code:

```
open (CMDOUT, "df -h 2>&1 |");
```

Comment: This is not good enough as quoting a whole command as a string suibjects you to injection attacks.